# Gecko Driver not navigating to URL

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browsers, firefoxdriver, vb.net

i am having a funny issue with my gecko driver. The browser loads however it does not redirect to the URL as stated below.

```
    Dim fireDriver As  New FireFoxDriver(New FireFoxOptions() With {.BrowserExecutableLocation = "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"})                
                handler.WebsiteLogin(fireDriver)

    fireDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.co.uk")
```

I am using firefox 57.0.3 (64-bit), geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64 and written in a VB .Net desktop application.

This is the trace from the driver

```
1514898589674   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:63088
1514898590827   mozprofile::profile     INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\GRANTP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.Mt3alKOXTMmE
1514898590829   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
1514898590847   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:63121
1514898592849   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG     connection attempt 0/600
1514898594955   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG     connection attempt 1/600
1514898597059   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG     connection attempt 2/600
1514898599160   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG     connection attempt 3/600
1514898601264   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG     connection attempt 4/600
1514898603368   geckodriver::marionette DEBUG     connection attempt 5/600
```

If i need to provide any other details please let me know so i can update the question.

Comment: Have to try to put geckdriver path ? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23091482/setting-up-selenium-with-vb-net    and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39016134/geckodriver-exe-not-in-current-directory-or-path-variable-selenium-2-53-1-fir

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the error with the selenium 2.53.1 version earlier today. After upgrading selenium standalone jar to 3.7.1, the issue is resolved. Can you try this.

Comment: Checked out selenium versions and we are currently sitting on version 3.8.0

Comment: still are you getting the same error?

Comment: Same as before. just keeps on trying to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all the top software testing companies are using geckodriver these days. Make sure that you are using the latest version of the Firefox and have a run, If it doesn't work then you can make the below mentioned changes and it will work.

You need to pass this argument `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar -enablePassThrough false`. Also you can [refer to the this release notes.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading selenium webdriver and firefox version will help this, Also try to update the geckodriver, there was a specific bug for Firefox ers version's

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue 15 days back.Kindly upgrade your firefox version to 61 and geckodriver version 0.21 and make sure you are using maranotte property as true it will work

Comment: Sorry but that is not the case. the main thing here that it faces is that it does not fire off the Redirect to URL command.

Comment: Use profile function and add path of your  firefox profile